# browser.js:173 Uncaught Error: process.binding is not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, request

As soon as I am adding block of code which is using `request` plugin. I am getting this error. No clue why its coming and what to do.

Gone through [discussions](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/815) of installing `url`, but not yet successful.

Here's my code:

```
export function serviceCall(token, method, url, body) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let start = new Date();
    let reqObj = {
      method,
      url: `${config.api}/${url}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: token
      }
    };
    if (body) {
      reqObj.body = body;
      reqObj.json = true;
    }
    request(
      reqObj,
      function (error, response, body) {
        try {
          if (!error && (response.statusCode === 200 || response.statusCode === 201 || response.statusCode === 204)) {
            if (typeof body === 'object') {
              return resolve(body);
            }
            return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
          }
          // The error messages are actually getting sent in the body
          return reject(JSON.stringify(body));
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

Error:

```
browser.js:173 Uncaught Error: process.binding is not supported
    at Object.process.binding (browser.js:173)
    at Object.eval (util.js:3)
    at eval (util.js:1053)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:6628)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at eval (stream.js:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:6700)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of search, i came across one solution. This problem is been caused by one of the plugin `react-scripts` I was using in the app. And after updating that plugin to latest version to `0.8.2` it worked for me. I am leaving this answer for the people who may face the similar popular in future.

[Reference](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/815)

Comment: I have react-scripts version 1.0.10 but still I have this issue